# Error en Visual Basic para aplicaciones (VBA)

Tags: vba

Tengo la siguiente función en en Excel pero  me salta el depurador y no soy capaz de encontrar dónde tengo el error. A ver si alguien me puede echar una mano.

```
Function CONTARCOLORCELDA(celdaOrigen As Range, celdaOrigen1 As Range, rango As Range)
 
Application.Volatile
 
'Variables
Dim celda As Range

'Recorremos todas las celdas del rango
For Each celda In rango
 
'Compara la propiedad Interior.Color
If celda.Font.Color = celdaOrigen.Font.Color And celda.Interior.Color = celdaOrigen.Interior.Color Then
CONTARCOLORCELDA = CONTARCOLORCELDA + 1
 
End If
Next celda

End Function
```

Comment: Si salta el depurador, muestra un error.. por favor agregalo...

Comment: Si recuerdo, el problema es que no debe declarar celda y uselo dentro de un for each.

Comment: A mi me ha funcionado. Lo que es incorrecto es que declaras la variable tipo Range que llamas "celdaOrigen1" y luego no la utilizas para nada. 
Si te muestra error es porque algo tienes tú en tu rango de celdas que nosotros no estamos teniendo en cuenta. Pasa el error que obtienes para poder ayudarte.